# How to return a "primitive Java char" from Scala?

Tags: java, scala, char

If I write:

```
def getShort(b: Array[Byte]): Short
```

in Scala, I get a primitive short in Java, which is fine. But if I write:

def getChar(b: Array[Byte]): Char

I get a scala.Char object, which is NOT fine. And if I write:

```
def getChar(b: Array[Byte]): Character
```

I get a java.lang.Character, which ISN'T fine either.

If Scala "Char" isn't Java "char", and Scala "Character" isn't Java "char", then what is left?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mistaken; `Char` *is* the Java primitive char.  Observe:

```
scala> class IsPrimitiveChar {
     |   def myChar(i: Int): Char = i.toChar   // I am clearly a Char, whatever that is!
     | }
defined class IsPrimitiveChar

scala> :javap IsPrimitveChar
Compiled from "<console>"
public class IsPrimitiveChar extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public char myChar(int);  // Look, it returns a char!
    public IsPrimitiveChar();
}


scala> :javap -c -private IsPrimitiveChar
Compiled from "<console>"
public class IsPrimitiveChar extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
public char myChar(int);
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   i2c               // Look, primitive int to char conversion in bytecode!
   2:   ireturn           // And that's all!
```

<sup>One needs to have tools.jar on the classpath for `:javap` to work, by the way.  It's included with the Sun/Oracle JVMs.</sup>

Comment: *I* am not mistaken. Eclipse is! So annoying! It gives me an error saying I get a scala.Char instead of a char, but at the console it works!

Comment: Better file a bug report, if it's not already there (and not already fixed, and you like using an IDE).

Answer (score 3):

I believe both will resolve to a primitive.

```
scala> def getShort(b: Array[Byte]): Short = 0
getShort: (b: Array[Byte])Short

scala> getShort(Array(1))
res10: Short = 0

scala> getShort(Array(1)).getClass().getName()
res11: java.lang.String = short

scala> def getChar(b: Array[Byte]): Char = 'a'
getChar: (b: Array[Byte])Char

scala> getChar(Array(1))
res13: Char = a

scala> getChar(Array(1)).getClass().getName()
res14: java.lang.String = char
```

Comment: Yes, Eclipse made fun of me again.

Answer (score 3):

Scala's `Char` is `scala.Char`, which is the same thing as `char`, just like `AnyRef` is the same thing as `Object`. To the JVM, it is `char`, to Scala, it is `scala.Char`.

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.Character is as good for java  as primitive for most purposes.   In case you really need  primitive you can just return charValue() off object

Comment: My point was that I don't want to create an object for every char; after all, I don't have to do it for all other primitive types.